# Why object assignment is not allowed in a class outside a method

Tags: c#, oop

In any c# class this is allowed

```
Class Program
{
 Dub obj=new Dub()
}
```

But not this

```
Class Program
{
Dub obj1= null;
Obj1=new Dub();
}
```

Try this in class only not in any function.

Comment: have you tried renaming "Obj1" to "obj1"? This cannot work!

Comment: yes, this is how C# language is defined (feel free to use constructor) ... where is the question?

Comment: The first line `Dub Obj1 = null;` is an object initialization, the second `Obj1 = new Dub();` is a statement and cannot exist outside a function.

Comment: Why you specifically need such statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language is designed to separate your "things" (class fields and class properties) from how to use them (methods). However, certain things are just *syntactic sugar* that allows you to be more concise.

In fact, your code

```
Class Program
{
    Dub obj=new Dub()
}
```

is functionally (and semantically) equivalent to this

```
Class Program
{
    Dub obj;

    public Program()
    {
        obj = new Dub();
    }
}
```

because it declares a field (`Dub obj` is the portion of code that does that) and then initializes it when it is constructed (`= new Dub()` is how you say that you want it initialized).

You may wonder why you have two ways to do the same things, but the point is that what you are writing in the initializer must be an *expression* that can be assigned to the field which is being initialized.
It is a constrained thing that you can use to have less code to write and review when things are easy. If that is not suitable, you can use the constructor, where you are free to do all the fancy things that are not allowed in the initializer.

Simply put, *Instructions* are almost unconstrained statements that can be used inside methods. An *expression* is an instruction, but not vice versa. Initializers require *expressions* by design.

For more information on initializers, you can have a look at [Field MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), where everything is explained with more details and samples.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.